# Calculate the index of a Fredholm Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, operator-theory

So I have an operator $T$ in $L(l^p(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C}))$ that looks like this (sorry that the formating isn't great):

\begin{bmatrix}
\ddots 0 & \ddots0 & \ddots0 & \dots & \dots & \ddots0 \\
\ddots1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 \ddots \\
\ddots0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 \ddots \\
\ddots0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & \dots & 0 \ddots \\
\vdots & \dots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & 0 \ddots \\
\vdots & \dots & \dots & 0\ddots  & 1\ddots  & 0 \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}

So basically its 0 everywhere except for diagonal line directly under the main diagonal, where its allways 1.

Since the index of $T$ is $indT = dimKer(T) - dimCoker(T)$ I was trying to figure out how to calculate the dimension of the Kernel and coKernel of $T$ but i couldn't find anything about it ($cokerT:=\{l^p(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})/ran(T)\}$.

If this were a matrix in $\mathbb{C}$ like:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &  0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
I could use a basis for $\mathbb{C}^3$ like <(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)> and get the dimension of the Kernel = 1 and the coKernel = 1, but since $T$ has infinite entries I don't really know what to do.

If you know how to calculate the index of $T$ or know a book where this is done that would be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operator is known as the *bilateral shift*. It is a unitary; as such, it is invertible and so its index is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the name, I didn't know it was called that. When I loooked it up it's mentioned here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) that it has index -1. Can you elaborate on why the operator is invertible?

Comment: Ok I think I understand why the index difference. In the wikepidea page the operator was in $l^p(\mathbb{N})$

Comment: The *unilateral* shift is not invertible. If an operator is invertible, both its kernel and its cokernel are zero.